# How to ignore a type with XStream?

Tags: java, serialization, xstream

with [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/), how can I ignore the serialization of a defined Type (for instance, when serializing a GUI, i want to ignore all swing types)?

Or if i want to ignore all javax.* types?

Thanks in advance,
Burkhard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to write a custom converter for the types you want to ignore.

For example, if you want to ignore the JLabels:

```
public class MyJLabelConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
        return clazz.equals(JLabel.class);
    }
}
```

and register it with:

```
xstream.registerConverter(new MyJLabelConverter());
```